# Error while passing IComparable<T> to CompareTo

Tags: c#, icomparable

I have a following code:

```cs
public class Foo<T>
{
    private IComparable<T> a { get; set; }
    
    public int foo(IComparable<T> b)
    {
        return a.CompareTo(b); // compile error : Argument type 'System.IComparable<T>' is not assignable to parameter type 'T?'
    }
}
```

> Argument type 'System.IComparable' is not assignable to parameter type 'T?'

How can I avoid this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a generic constraint at the class level to ensure that `T` implements `IComparable<T>`. Then replace `IComparable<T>` in the property and parameter type with just `T`.

```
public class Foo<T> where T : IComparable<T>
{
    private T a { get; set; }

    public int foo(T b)
    {
        return a.CompareTo(b);
    }
}
```